# initialize a vector of vectors of arrays returns an error

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

i would like to initialize a vector of vectors of arrays like this

```
vector<vector<int[4]>> gri =  

{
    {{8,5,9,4},{9,1,5,9},{6,9,6,6}},
    {{7,4,6,1},{6,8,3,4},{1,1,9,0}},
    {{9,6,0,4},{0,4,8,2},{5,9,1,8}}
};
```

i'm novice in c++ but i think i'm doing right the error i'm getting is

`array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initialize`

i can't identify the issue, despite i'm using brace-enclosed, can anyone tell me what's wrong in my code please.

Comment: Vector template arguments cannot be array types (like your `int[4]`). Perhaps you want a `std::vector<std::array<int, 4>>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an array:

```
vector<vector<array<int,4>>>
```

You can't store `int[4]` in a vector directly.

Comment: can you advise me a data structure for tetravex game ? is this one goos for that kind of programs

Comment: Yes, use a vector of vector of arrays.